# cannot Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3, frontend, template-hints

Cannot Enable **Template Path Hints** for **Storefront** in **Magento 2.3**

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Have you enable it on store level and make sure there is no IP restriction.

Comment: did it worked ?

Comment: Thanks. 
It still does not work

Comment: Have you tried enabling developer mode? php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143335)

Comment: yes the mode is developer

Comment: Flush the magento cache and try again.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 6):

Template path hint is disabled in **Production mode**

You need to first set it to **development mode**

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer --skip-compilation
```

After changing to developer mode you need to run static deploy on admin theme

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend -f
```

Clean cache at the end

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Note:** If above solution didn't work for you then apply these commands

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer --skip-compilation
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**After this template path hint should be visible on admin :)**

Answer (score 3):

**I strongly discourage this method. Use it at your own risk. Only to be used on local system.**

Open `vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/TemplateEngine/Plugin/DebugHints.php` (tested in 2.3.2)

write this code inside `afterCreate` function : (at the start, above the storecode line)

```
if(isset($_GET['shreyasPathHints']) && $_GET['shreyasPathHints'] == 'on'){
    return $this->debugHintsFactory->create([
        'subject' => $invocationResult,
        'showBlockHints' => 1,
    ]);
}
```

Now, you can open any Magento page and append `?shreyasPathHints=on` to the URL. No need to run any commands.

Answer (score 1):

Enable template path hints from Magento Admin >> Stores >> Configuration >> Advanced >> Developer.

After enabling, append "templatehints=magento" in URL like "http://localhost?templatehints=magento" and it will show template path hints.